# operator= is ambiguous for string set

Tags: c++

My Base class .h file

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include <ostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
typedef set<string> StringSet;

class Item
{
protected:
    string  title;
    StringSet keywords;
public:
    Item();
    Item(const string& title, const string& keywords);
    virtual ~Item();
    //virtual void addKeywords(string keyword) const;
    string getTitle();
    string getKeywords();

};
#endif
```

Inherited class .cpp file

```
#include "Book.h"

Book::Book()
{
    title =     "no title";
    keywords = { "no keywords" }; // error
    author =    "no author";
    pagesNr =   0;

}
```

Why do I get an "C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous" for this line `keywords = { "no keywords" };`, and how can it be solved?
Thank you.

Comment: Is it all the compiler says?

Comment: `c:\users\evghenii\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\proj4cs261\proj4cs261\musicalbum.cpp(7): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
1>          e:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\set(180): could be 'std::set<std::string,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Kty>> &std::set<_Kty,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Kty>>::operator =(std::initializer_list<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>          ]`

Comment: that might be a compiler overloading bug. try
`keywords = {{"no keywords"}};`

Comment: it gives the same error

Comment: Please add the full compiler to the question, properly formatted.

Comment: I have made a quick test in an online compiler and it compiles fine. [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4700f1eddc8eade)

Comment: If it makes you feel better, gcc-5.1 with `-std=c++11` compiles your code w/o any problem

Comment: Make sure that you selected C++11 dialect and well you have updated your MSVC :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal "working" (gives the same error) example is

```
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> keywords;
    keywords = { "no keywords" }; // error

    return 0;
}
```

You should also say you use VS 2013. The initializer list is not fully supported in VS 2013, but if you compile with VS 2015 everything compiles fine.

Comment: Thanks for providing a simpler example.  I've just compiled without error with GCC 4.8.2 (with `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra`), so this appears to be a quality-of-implementation issue.

Answer (score 2):

`{ "no keywords" }` is an initializer list and apparently Visual Studio cannot use the assignment operator for a `std::set<std::string>` with the inializer list.
Instead, you can employ the constructor for the set directly:

```
Book::Book()
 : keywords({ "no keywords" })
{
    title =     "no title";
    author =    "no author";
    pagesNr =   0;

}
```